# EFCore Many-To-Many relationship with the same table on the ends

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, ef-core-3.1

I want to track referrals for users. There are two entities classes.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Referral> Referrees { get; set; }
}

public class Referral
{
    public long ReferrerId { get; set; }
    public long ReferreeId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Referrer { get; set; }
    public virtual User Referree { get; set; }
}
```

I defined relationships between them through fluent API on model creating (for the Referral entity)

```
builder.HasOne(r => r.Referrer).WithMany(u => u.Referrals).HasForeignKey(r => r.ReferrerId);
builder.HasOne(r => r.Referree).WithMany(u => u.Referrees).HasForeignKey(u => u.ReferreeId);
```

But when I try adding a migration, I get the

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Referral.Referrer' of type 'User'. Either manually configure
>   the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Except for missing PKs (which I guess you simply forgot to include in the post), nothing wrong with what you have shown here. Make sure the shown relationship fluent code is actually executed, because the exception in question happens when you leave the above model without fluent configuration.

Comment: Yes, I excluded some stuff, including PKs in order to simplify the question. And it does get executed, because when I remove the Referrer property, the migration gets created successfully.

Comment: Well, then there is something else not shown here. Added `public long Id { get; set; }` to `User` + `builder.HasKey(r => new { r.ReferrerId, r.ReferreeId });` to your code and migration is added w/o a problem.